# Can a variable name determined by array value in a for-loop?

Tags: javascript, function, variables, for-loop

Is it possible to use an array variable value as a new variable name in a for-loop (or in other words, can the left-hand side of an equation be determined by a pre-defined value in an iteration)?

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    // we all know this is possible:
    blabla[i] = apple;
    // but I'm wondering if there's a way we can achieve this:
    example(someVar);
}

function example(name) {
   // [name] = banana;
   name = banana;
}
```

Obviously, the way I'm doing this in the snippet above, the value `banana` is always getting assigned to the variable `name`. Not too sure though how I could go about this?

Comment: Please clarify what you actually want to achieve.  It's not clear from your example.  What would be the point of assigning a random variable (_banana_) to a local variable (_name_) in a function?  And what is _someVar_ (you provide zero context whatsoever for _banana_ and _someVar_).

Comment: Maybe I should have asked this question differently. Basically what I want is to able to do something like `eval(someVar) = someValue`. Is that possible? @jahroy

Comment: That doesn't make sense.  You should have a variable on the left side of an assignment statement. Looks like you figured it out, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variables are properties, either of the global object (in a browser: `window`) or of some other object. So you can do:

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
   window[array[i]] = '[something]';
}
```

or

```
var someObj = {};
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
   someObj[array[i]] = '[something]';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function myVar(val) {
this.value=val;
}

var array=new Array( new myVar(1),new myVar(2),new myVar(3));

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    example(array[i]);
    alert(array[i].value); // now they are 0,0,0
}

function example(name) {
   name.value = 0;
}
```